# AngularJS navigation et reload tabbed page

Tags: angularjs, tabs, routes

In my application I have a page that display several tabs. All the informations are gathered with a single HTTP request. Every tab contains an HTML form. By default on the load of the page we load the first tab. After a modification within any tab we reload the page for informations refresh (following en INSERT/UPDATE in a backend database). What we want: if before any update we were on a particular tab (any other than the first one), to return on the same tab.

I thought at several solutions:

1. To use different URL for different tabs (panes), namely URL routing. For example, `domain.ext/page/tab`. There, I have a problem because the URL must update following user trace. If the user click on a 3rd tab, we have to change the URL to `domain.ext/page/3rd-tab` using $location.path() which triggers page reloading.
2. To use the same URL (what we have now) and anchors in the page managed by $location.search() and reloadOnSearch = false. For example, `domain.ext/page?pane=tab`. There, I have another problem because the query string (that is managed by $location.search()) is kept at service level and when the user goes on another page, the query string is the same (`domain.ext/another-page?pane=tab`). I would like to delete the query string when the user leaves the page.
3. To use ui-route. This solution change lot of the actual structure of the application.

IMHO the 2nd solution seems better except that I don’t know where and when to reset query string.

I’d like your opinions on this topic.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it necessary to reload the page after the insert/update, can you not refetch the information and repopulate the fields silently?  

Another suggestion is to use localStorage to keep track of the tab that the user had chosen.

Comment: code? what are you using for routing? ui-route or ngRoute.

Comment: For Shah: We use a REST paradigm so refetching needs reloading (HTTP GET). This round trip is necessary for refreshing after triggers or stored procedures updates in the database. Even if we use localStorage, we need to reset on a location change and that is not so 'correct'

Comment: For Aaron: Now we use ngRoute. ui-route would be a solution only if we change the whole structure of the application